# Making a bookcase look perfectly flush with the wall when the wall is not a true 90 degrees

Tags: furniture, finishing, built-ins

How would one go about fixing this highlighted gap in the photo:

[image]
[image]

The bookcases are attached together and level (though the potato quality photo may not make it appear that way)

But as you can tell from the zoomed in version, since the wall is not a true 90 degrees, there's an annoying little gap.

What is the best way of remedying this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to take a board of the right height, plumb it with the bookcase next to the wall.  Then take a compass or something to hold your pencil at the right distance and scribe a line along the board following the wall contour.  Start at the bottom where it's closest to the bookcase.  You don't want to leave such a thin edge that it's hard to cut.  I'd probably want half an inch minimum.  Cut the scribed line with a jigsaw.

Then attach to the side, flush with the front edge and it should sit against the wall with no gaps.  I might cut another board and put it along the side of the bookcase at the bottom so I can shove the bookcase into the corner and not stress the facade piece.

Comment: You could call this the 'typical' method. This is what you'd normally want to do.

Comment: This is known as scribing to fit.

Comment: You'll notice that nearly every kitchen cabinet that ends against a wall has a vertical board as described. This situation is the reason.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to mask the variation is to move the book case unit away from the corner a small amount. Having a margin that is overall 3 or 4 times larger than the gap you see now will make the difference not be noticeable unless you really go measuring for it.

Answer (score 1):

Quick & Easy Solution:

- if there's any chance that the shelving may jiggle: use shims to prevent most, if not all, of the jiggle (score shims w/ box cutter & snap to trim excess shim flush w/ shelving)
- using a paintable, flexible caulking, fill in gap about 1/2" deep along the space between shelving and wall (using finger to create a *very slight* concave profile...like one would when caulking a shower stall)
- paint caulking to match wall.